# PHP contact form keep input fields if error, otherwise clear

Tags: php, post, contact-form

I want my contact form input fields to save the user's inputs if there's an error, otherwise have them cleared if the email goes through. Right now it works except when the email is sent the fields are still filled in. I could refresh the page but then it doesn't show the 'Your email has been sent' message.

Here's my form:

```
<form class="contact-form" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["name"])) echo $_POST["name"]; ?>" />
</form>
```

I tried adding something to my php code that handles the email business - if the message was sent, `unset($_POST["name"])`, and also adding to this form input's php `else echo '';` but that didn't seem to work. It seems the variable was still set.

Comment: After the email is successfully sent, redirect to the same page, but for example with the `?sent` parameter. Then on the page you check if `isset($_GET['sent'])` and display a success message. The form will be empty, and you will avoid the situation that someone refreshing the page will send the email again.

Comment: How do I add the GET method for `?sent` when the form I'm submitting is a post? I added this below my form `<p id="output-area"><?php if(isset($_GET["sent"])) echo 'Message has been sent.'; ?></p>`. I'm not sure how to set `?sent` from my php file that checks if the inputs are good and sends the email. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that your page is `contact.php`.

You php code should be something like this:

```
// we will keep here error message
$error = '';

// if request is get and isset sent
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET" and isset($_GET["sent"]))
    echo '<p id="output-area">Message has been sent.</p>';
else {
    // if request is post
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
        // then verify input data
        if (!empty($_POST['msg'])) {
            // if mail was sent, redirect to contact.php?sent
            if (mail("someone@example.com", "My subject", $_POST['msg'])){
                header('Location: contact.php?sent');
                exit;
            } else
                $error = "Mail does not sent.";
        } else
            $error = 'Please fill in all inputs.';
    }
}

if ($error != '')
   echo '<p class="error">Error: ' . $error . '</p>';

// here goes your form
echo '<form class="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="msg">' . (!empty($_POST["msg"]) ? $_POST["msg"] : '') . '</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set error flag while error occurred. try this

$error=false;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

```
$msg =  $_POST['msg'];

if(mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg)){

    
}else{
    
    $error = "mail does not sent";
}
```

}

" />